# Lenovo T440p Docking Station USB only works half the time

Tags: usb, lenovo, 15.04, docking

I've recently bought a Lenovo T440p and have realized that USB devices connected via its docking station do not connect if I boot the computer while it's plugged into it. When I boot the laptop when it's not connected to the docking station, and then plug it into the docking station, they work just fine. Why is this and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: I've worked out a way to reset usb and networking during boot that correct the issue.

Comment: You should answer your own question and share the insight you've gained.

Comment: please post your solution, I'm facing similar issue, in my case, ocationally,  the USB stops to work for some minutes, and after came back

Comment: Uuuuugh I am having a similar problem with a brand-new T460s. What's the solution, @PeterBucher? This is like Fermat's Last AskUbuntu Comment!